# Gimp's flame plugin for Blender

Tags: materials, modifiers

Gimp's flame plugin is a tool for creating cosmic recursive fractal flames. Could it be done for Blender as some object/mesh/curves with halo material?

It can be 2D. Just so we could animated it. I've made this in Gimp. 
This is flame plugin link https://github.com/piksels-and-lines-orchestra/gimp/tree/master/plug-ins/flame

[image: flame1]

Comment: Somewhat related: http://www.blendernation.com/2014/12/24/add-on-attraction/

Comment: Thanks. Could someone wrote this flame plugin for Blender. It's open source.